# Display runtime QR code image in email without storing in yii2 PHP

Tags: php, email, yii2, qr-code

I've used one extension to generate a QR code in yii2 PHP (https://github.com/tecnickcom/tc-lib-barcode)

And by documentation, I followed this.

```
// instantiate the barcode class
$barcode = new \Com\Tecnick\Barcode\Barcode();

// generate a barcode
$bobj = $barcode->getBarcodeObj(
    'QRCODE,H',                     // barcode type and additional comma-separated parameters
    'https://tecnick.com',          // data string to encode
    -4,                             // bar width (use absolute or negative value as multiplication factor)
    -4,                             // bar height (use absolute or negative value as multiplication factor)
    'black',                        // foreground color
    array(-2, -2, -2, -2)           // padding (use absolute or negative values as multiplication factors)
    )->setBackgroundColor('white'); // background color

// output the barcode as HTML div (see other output formats in the documentation and examples)
echo $bobj->getHtmlDiv();
```

I have a requirement that generates a QR code and that QR code we have to send in an email.
The email code is ready, in that we have mapped <img> image tag to display images. And if we pass any stored image path then the image is showing and the email code is working fine.
But I'm facing a challenge while displaying the QR code in the email. I've executed the above code through Postman and QR code is showing but not on email.

```
 $bobj->getHtmlDiv();
```

Beside this function I've also tried.

```
 $bobj->getPng();
```

```
 $bobj->getSvg();
```

But not working

Can anyone please tell us how we can render it?
Or is there any other extension that will be easy to use and implement?

Tried the functions

```
  $result = $bobj->getHtmlDiv();
```

```
  $result = $bobj->getPng();
```

```
 $result = $bobj->getSvg();
```

But not able to send it on email.

Also tried to pass result of the below code in file object. still image only came in postman and not file object.

```
file_get_contents()
```

Tried this as well but not able to resolve.

Comment: So where is the part where you tried to add this into your email? If you don't want to store it on your server, then you will either have to use one of the variants that create HTML (will probably need additional CSS, I suppose, could be tricky in an email) or SVG and add those to your HTML mail body directly; or if you use PNG, you will have to "inline" it.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to embed or attach the image of barcode you have to use
[`getPngData()`](https://github.com/tecnickcom/tc-lib-barcode/blob/2b87f7c63dfd05000445a202c1779aeb9eb4549d/src/Type.php#L476) method instead of [`getPng()`](https://github.com/tecnickcom/tc-lib-barcode/blob/2b87f7c63dfd05000445a202c1779aeb9eb4549d/src/Type.php#L453). This is because `getPng()` doesn't simply return the data of image but it sets the headers and outputs the result directly.

After you get the image data with `getPngData()` you can use [`yii\mail\MessageInterface::embedContent()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-mail-messageinterface#embedContent()-detail) to embed the image in mail without saving it anywhere.

Assuming you already have the barcode object in `$bobj` property then in mail template you can do something like this:

```html
<img src="<?= $message->embedContent(
    $bobj->getPngData(),
    [
        'fileName' => 'barcode.png',
        'contentType' => 'image/png',
    ]
); ?>" alt="barcode">
```